# UML or CASE tool to analyze *huge* JavaScript code base?

Tags: javascript, uml, code-visualization, case-tools

I have to figure out how a huge JavaScript code base works and I'm wondering if there are any CASE/UML tools to analyze its structure. I understand that there are several limitations because of the dynamic typing and existence of `eval()`, but I suppose if IDEs can offer meaningful inspections for JavaScript code these days, there must be some way to visualize dependencies, etc.

Comment: Huge enough that I can't hold it all in my brain at once :)

Answer (score 0):

use JS/UML which is an eclipse plugin from jsuml.org

Answer (score 0):

WAVI Web Application Viewer 2 (Node.js)

Generate a svg class diagram for your node.js web application.

WAVI is intended for developers who wish to document their web application or as a reverse engineering tool to recover the structure of a web application.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/wavi